# Rails RoutingError (uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm trying to create a simple registration model that will respond only to json:

```
class Api::RegistrationController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json
  def register
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      render :status => "OK"
    else
      render :status => "ERROR"
    end
  end
end
```

When trying to register I get:

```
Started POST "/api/register" for 10.0.0.4 at 2013-07-22 07:45:44 +0300
Processing by Api::RegistrationController#register as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"mmm@mmm.mmm"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"mmm@mmm.mmm"}}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `sign_up_params' for #<Api::RegistrationController:0x4eca9e0>):
  app/controllers/api/registration_controller.rb:5:in `register'
```

This is obvious because I'm trying to use **sign_up_params** that belong do Devise.

So next I try to inherit:

```
class Api::RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationController
```

Restart server and getting this error:

```
Started POST "/api/register" for 10.0.0.4 at 2013-07-22 07:50:03 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Devise::RegistrationController):
  app/controllers/api/registration_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is my routes:

```
Notter12::Application.routes.draw do
  post "api/register" => "api/registration#register"

  devise_for :users
.
.
.
```

Rake:

```
            api_register POST   /api/register(.:format)        api/registration#register
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   notes GET    /notes(.:format)               notes#index
                         POST   /notes(.:format)               notes#create
                new_note GET    /notes/new(.:format)           notes#new
               edit_note GET    /notes/:id/edit(.:format)      notes#edit
                    note GET    /notes/:id(.:format)           notes#show
                         PUT    /notes/:id(.:format)           notes#update
                         DELETE /notes/:id(.:format)           notes#destroy
                    root        /                              notes#index

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
class Api::RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  def register
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      render :json => {:result => 'OK'}
    else
      render :json => {:result => 'ERROR'}
    end
  end
end
```

Also had to change routes.rb:

```
devise_scope :user do
    post "api/register" => "api/registration#register"
  end
  devise_for :users
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please rename it to

`Devise::RegistrationsController` not **Registration** it should be **Registrations**

thanks hope it will work

Comment: Thanks... I should not always trust auto complete.